# Clearing the concept of definition

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

What is the definition in general?

This question has arised mainly due to the fact that the word "sphere" is used for 3-dimensional space. What if I want to define for any space? For a real line or for n-dimensional space?

I am afraid whether I am using wrong textbook. The definition goes like:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $x$ be in $X$ and $r$ be any non negative real number. The open sphere with centre $x$ and radius $r$ is the subset of $X$ given by the set of all $y$ in $X$ such that $d(x,y)<r$.

Comment: Sorrry, its d(x,y)<r.

Comment: That looks like an open ball to me.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not getting my doubt clear.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what your confusion is. If you are looking for a more general definition, this is already a general definition.

Comment: Okey, but the confusion is Can we use the word sphere for any space in general? Or it is like we say its open ball in R and open sphere in R2.

Comment: We can. In fact, $R^2$ is just a special metric space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your definition, the term *sphere* is defined on a metric space. Indeed, if you read the definition, it only involves a set $X$ and a metric $d$ that is defined on the set $X$.

So you are right. What you call "3-dimensional space", which is $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a metric space. Usually we equip it with the Euclidean norm. More than that, it makes perfect sense talking about sphere in even higher dimensional space such as $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Just to add one more interesting thing. We can not only change the set $X$ but we can also change the metric $d$. It doesn't have to be Euclidean metric. It can be, for example, Taxicab metric or the metric derived from the [supremum norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm).